# How can I create a Regex filter in Slate Platform Editor?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

I’m using Slate Platform Editor and I would like to create an object set with a filter using a Regular Expression (Regex). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may have noticed, the Platform tab's Object Set panel is ideal for [simple filtering](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/ontology-object-sets/):
[image: object set panel]

Or for using [multi-term filters and wildcard filters](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/ontology-object-sets/#object-set-filter-builder-mode):
[image: more complex filter]

To perform more advanced search with Regular Expression, you will have to use the [Platform tab's Foundry functions panel](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/concepts-platform/#foundry-functions-panel) and create a specific function for your filtered object set:
[image: regex filter]

Please find here an example with an input being a Regex to illustrate how you can proceed (you can also remove the input and specify the Regex directly in the function):
[image: code repo]